# How to access another Site with event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, event-receivers

I am doing an event receiver which updates a list from another Site, I don't know how to access another site using CSOM

Answer (score 0):

Grant your add-in with tenant Read permission and depoy the add-in as a tenant scoped add-in.

Then use cross domain library to access other site collection.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, targetUrl);
ctx.Load(appContextSite.get_web());
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/

Comment: I think this snippet does not work with Sharepoint Online